# uiviewcontroller embeded in uinavigation controller starts under parent view's navigation bar in iphone x

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

[image][image]

I am using following code to add child view controller within another viewcontroller.

```
  CGRect rightViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-50);
    
    [pWorksetController viewDidAppear:YES];
    
    UIStoryboard *pModelViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ModelViewMobile" bundle:nil];
   gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController =
    (ModelViewController*)[pModelViewStoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VIEW_DETAIL"];
    // pModelViewController.selectedModel = pModelListInfo;
    gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController.DiscussionViewListingDelegate = self;
    //offline model
    gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController.syncAllButton = self.syncAllButton;
    //offline model
    //[self UpdateView];
    gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController.modelViewDelegate = self;
    gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton =TRUE;
    self.pRightNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:gpUserDataManager.pModelViewController];
    [self.pRightNavController.view setFrame:rightViewFrame];
    self.pRightNavController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    self.pRightNavController.view.clipsToBounds =  YES;
    self.pRightNavController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.pRightNavController.view];  
    [self addChildViewController:self.pRightNavController];
```

Childviewcontroller's navigation is not starting from proper position.It comes under navigation bar.Please see attached screenshot-1.This only happens while running application on iphone x.It looks properly in other devices.How to resolve this?

**Update:** When i uncheck under top bars and bottom bars it shifts uiviewcontroller below.Please refer to second screenshot-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just uncheck:**

```
Under Top Bars 
Under Bottom Bars
```

[image]

Comment: When i uncheck top bars and bottom bars it shifts child viewcontroller to  down and leaves gap at top.Please refer to first screen-shot attached

Comment: Only uncheck Under Top Bars only @Bhoomi

let the Under Bottom Bar check.

Comment: Even if i only uncheck under top bars and keep under bottom bar check, result is same.It still shifts uiviewcontroller below and leaves gap.

Comment: Instead of adding subview Can you present it?